# pyCharm does not find module "time"

Tags: python, pycharm

In a project I am working on, my pyCharm does not find the standard library "time", see screenshot. The other libraries are found without any problem.  I am using pyCharm Community 2017.3, and a virtualenv created by anaconda. In the tool tip, pyCharm says "No module named time"

[image]

What I don't understand is, time is part of Python standard library. Why cannot pyCharm find it while it has no problem finding the other libraries I use?

The script can be executed in pyCharm. Apparently, pyCharm does find and load "time" at runtime. It seems the error message is only an editor thing.

Comment: Does it actually *say* the module is not found, or is it possible it's some other type of error? Like unused module, defefined variable name later, something like that? All I see is a red underline.

Comment: I take it that the name of this file *is not* `time.py`, correct? If it is, then here is your problem

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen it actually says "no module named time"

Comment: What is the traceback when you run it?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is mostly related to the interpreter selection. So here's something I am not very sure of. Try this. While selecting the new project, make sure you click on the gear icon for local interpreter selection. [click on the gear icon to select the local interpreter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjVjo.jpg)

Then go on to select the local interpreter option
[Local interpreter selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOwgF.jpg)

As for the Time module it works.